# DocuSign API - Envelope Tab to show day and month of date signed

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on an integration with the DocuSign API - so far so good. The paper version of the document I'm working with has the following paragraph:

```
The Contract is entered into on the ___ day of _________, ____
```

On paper the signer would enter the day of the month, the month and the year. We would like to automatically populate this so it auto enters the day, month and year of the current date/date the person is electronically signing this.

I've been looking through the list of [Envelope Tab Types](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs#tab-types) but haven't found anything so far that would automatically generate these as dynamic values based on the date signed.

Is there such a Tab Type for this or another way for DocuSign to generate this for us? We're trying to avoid having the signer having to enter this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign doesn't have the ability to do this yet, unless you use the API or PowerForms.

If you use the API or PowerForms to create the envelope, then you can explicitly set the values of the fields. (You'll need to calculate them in your application.)

There is the current capability to automatically set the `day`. To do so:

1. Add a `Date sent` field
2. Change the Data label for the field to be `dateSigned`
3. Change the Formatting options for the field to have a white color so it will be invisible on the page.
4. Add a formula field
5. Edit the formula for the formula field. Set it to `Day([dateSigned])`
6. Result: the formula field will show just the day of the date that the document was signed. Eg "30" Unfortunately it will not have the "th" suffix that you'd often like for an English reader.

[Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-calculated-fields)

There is an enhancement request for this. Ask DocuSign customer service to add your information to TRI-8003